# Result missing when iterating through a resultset with PHP PDO & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, image, memory, pdo

I'm developing a website with an image gallery. I want to list all images on a single page. So I wrote the script below.

```
try{
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdatabase';
    $conn = new PDO($dsn, 'user', 'xxxx');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $gallery_select_stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT image_id FROM images ORDER BY image_id ASC");
    $gallery_select_stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $gallery_select_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
            echo '<div class="imageBox">';
            echo '<a href="photo.php?id='.$value.'"><img src="image.php?id='.$value.'&thumb=1"/></a>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
} catch(Exception $ex){
    error_log("Issue processing the gallery: ".$ex);
}
```

I am testing the site with 6 images! But the first image is not displaying. I Googled the issue and found some similar question in stackoverflow as well. But none of them helped me!

The main issue I have is when I execute the above code replacing the

```
echo '<a href="photo.php?id='.$value.'"><img src="image.php?id='.$value.'&thumb=1"/></a>';
```

part with something like this

```
echo '<img src="images/'.$value.'"/></a>';
```

Code works perfectly. All the 6 results are displayed.

I must admit most of these images are quite large (varies between 4 - 12 MB, but the larger image is displayed). Is this a memory issue?

Comment: What does your network tab in the browser's development console say when the image doesn't get displayed?

Comment: What does your HTML source tab say on the generated HTML?

Comment: note that you don't need to use `foreach` for iterating `$row` because it contains only one value which can be get by `$row['image_id']`

Comment: What does it mean - "is not displaying" - is the database not returning the first id, or the <img href value returns 404 HTTP status code?

Comment: So, you are generating a thumbnail from a large image on each request? Or even sixh thumbnails from six large images?

Comment: @YourCommonSense HTML source tab displays all 6 images as rendered! Yeah I'm generating thumbnails

Comment: So I can only pity your tortured server.

Comment: @N.B. The troubled image's content length is zero in Response Header. How do I resolve it. The image is well, I mean you can view it using any other tool

Comment: @GundarsMēness No 404 Errors. The first result is not displaying.

Comment: clear cache and refresh...

Comment: @YourCommonSense Maybe I should quit generating thumbnails on the fly? Is it what you are suggesting? Thanks for you replies BTW

Comment: @Akam Clearing Cache & refreshing didn't work!

Comment: You're *probably* getting a 500 internal error or fatal error that you exceeded the memory limit. That's why instead of image, you get plaintext error message. Bottom line is that you shouldn't generate thumbs from large images on the fly, you should pre-generate them.

Comment: Check the error log and see what the problem is.

Comment: @N.B. Thanks N.B. I will do the same! However I didn't get any error, just the missing image. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @N.B.: but at that case the 6th image should be avoided not the first one, am I right?

Comment: @GundarsMēness Warning:  imagesy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\Apache\htdocs\DWphotography\\image.php on line 11, the code is `$originalHeight = imagesy($src);`

Comment: @Akam I think you are right! The GET request shows status 200 OK, but Size is zero??

Comment: @LalakaJ And did you check WHY $src is a boolean not an actual resource?

Comment: @GundarsMēness I pass the source of the image as a variable! But if i specify the source statically, it would display all images! Issue is solved. But it is necessary to pass the source image location as a variable. which is a string of the location of the image. How do I make it a resource

Comment: @LalakaJ That function has nothing to do with sources and strings. Don't misuse it. See doc http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesy.php

Comment: @GundarsMēness `imagesy` gets an image resource from `imagecreatefromjpeg` which is created from a string variable.

Comment: And all this image processing stuff under mysql and pdo tags...

Comment: @YourCommonSense To be honest I didn't expect this to be associated with image processing! But I added an image tag as well. After restarting the server it started working well.

Comment: A programmer should never *expect* or guess. But debug and find out the certain cause.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Sure! Sorry to offend you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an memory issue in the server. When I restarted Apache and re-run the script issue was resolved. @N.B. 's suggestion was correct, the images were far too large to be handled in an array.